# how will lambda function used in sorting

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, lambda

```
I.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],-x[1]))
```

suppose i have `I=[[1,2],[1,4],[3,4]]` then how will this lambda function will sort and can anyone explain  me about how it will do step by step

Comment: After sorting using this lambda function I will get I=[[1,4],[1,2],[3,4]]. But you are telling your sort will return nothing.

Comment: It will return nothing but it will modify the existing list right. I just wanted to know how it will get modified.

Answer (score 0):

What you're referring to is a complex search by multiple keys (1st AND 2nd keyes in your case):

1. Ascending by 1st key and
2. Descending by 2nd key.

This works for groups with ties.

What is happening can be illustrated by the following example:

```
I=[[1,2],[1,4],[3,4]]
func = lambda x: (x[0])
I.sort(key=func)
print("        Sort by 1st key:",I)

I=[[1,2],[1,4],[3,4]]
func = lambda x: (x[0], -x[1])
I.sort(key=func)
print("Sort by 1st AND 2nd key:",I)
        Sort by 1st key: [[1, 2], [1, 4], [3, 4]]
Sort by 1st AND 2nd key: [[1, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: @Manjunath Does it answer your question? If so you may kindly think about accepting it.